# How do I move the reticle to Ryder's left side?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

In this diagram, the `-`s are tall cover (i.e. cover tall enough that Ryder cannot shoot over it), the `R` is Ryder, and the `x`s are enemies:

```
x  x  x  x  x

  ------
  R
```

(For people with screen readers: Ryder is behind the left side of a tall bank of cover, with enemies in front.)

I want to peek around the left side of the cover and shoot at the enemies.  But Ryder always looks to my right, and the reticle is also on my right, so I can't shoot at anything from this position.  **How do I make Ryder look left instead of right?**

Comment: +1 for providing an accessible post (for screen reader users)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The button you're after is <kbd>ALT</kbd>, at least on the PC version. This button is bound to "Camera Swap/Recenter" and is the same binding as used to allow the game to use its cinematic camera angle when you're driving around in the Nomad.

On both console versions the equivalent action/binding appears to be clicking the right thumb stick.